# Cart getting empty in Magento2 or Magento2.0.8 cart persistence issue

Tags: magento2, persistent

In Magento 2.0.8 
in cart page if you click more than once Processed Checkout button cart getting empty 
but it will not  reproduce 2.1.0 and above

Answer (score 1):

its Magento default issue 
we can fix this issue by replacing SessionManager.php of 2.1 version

to get click below link

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/SessionManager.php

and replace SessionManager.php of Magento 2.0.8

Answer (score 0):

cart will become empty if user click processed checkout button in cart page  more than 1 or 2 times continuously before loading the page.

please check the code changes from 2.1.x

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/5130a5e48788e6cfb5c42d4eef707af0e3af30f7
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d2a823ba0b1187120d2baf657a4d971994357e8e

[image: ***enter image description here***]